# Wikitude SDK example for google glass

Tags: google-glass, augmented-reality, wikitude

Are there any sample codes for using wikitude sdk for google glass development? i am currently using android studio for my work. I want to create a geolocation AR experience for my users but the links on wikitude are all broken.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Wikitude provides SDK Sample Application as part of their GoogleGlass SDK in the [download section](http://www.wikitude.com/download)

Please also find documentation of it in the [Wikitude developer section](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/glass#_48_INSTANCE_9XjWBdf5iyrD_=gettingstartedsmartglasses.html%23google-glass).

Don't hesitate to ask any further questions directly in the [Wikitude Dev-Forum](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/developer-forum/-/message_boards/category/12424) for fast reply.

Kind regards,
Andreas